# Locked out of Samsung Galaxy S4 tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, locked-out

I cannot remember password on my tablet  Samsung Galaxy S4. It just keeps giving me options to enter, I've tried 30 times I should have never changed it in the middle of doing something.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This happens to be a question frequently asked on our site (already 2 times asked just today). Have you tried our on-site search? See [How do I search?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for help using it. // I've also added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please start checking [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for first aid, and follow up to the relevant posts linked from there. And check the "Related" section on this page :)

Answer (score 0):

If the S4 is connected to the Internet and has your Google Id logged in, then you can change your password using [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).

Answer (score 0):

You can use recovery mode option. You can erase cache partition.

Find my mobile is on then you can erase mobile using google account. You can also use Samsung account and erase mobile.

You can connect mobile to computer and restore mobile.
https://mobile-cellphones.blogspot.com/2021/02/howto-unlock-pattern-lock-and-password.html